# Rewrite rule not redirecting correctly

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm using the `Rewrite Plugin` from the Wordpress plugin site here: [Wordpress Plugin Page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rewrite)

I'm trying to get the following URL `homes-for-sale-details/4420/217007490/177/Fb-landing-page` to pull up a custom PHP page in the subdirectory `propertylisting1`. So this is my rule:

`^homes-for-sale-details/4420/217007490/177/Fb-landing-page(.*)$`

And I have it redirecting to `propertylisting1/index.php`

It seems to work because when I go to that URL it actually detects it, but it doesn't display the page I want it to display, it redirects me to the home page, completely redirects me.

[image]

I have the rule at the top also.

Comment: I don't know anything about that plugin, but it probably only deals with the internal rewrite system, where rules can only point to the main `index.php` file with the necessary query vars to load a WordPress object. Those are parsed in php, not by apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to not use plugins, just use Apache's built in HTAccess. The trick with HTAccess and Wordpress so as not to break wordpress rewrite features, is to place the new rule before the `RewriteCond` statement of wordpress. So the final looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^homes-for-sale-details/4420/217007490/177/Fb-landing-page(.*)$ propertylisting1/index.php?success=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

As you'll notice, I had to place it in-between the conditions for not found, and the base rewrite rule.

This way works perfectly fine and doesn't break any of Wordpress' own rules in the process.